# Override equals method to get unique records with latest details in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I have a model class like this:

```java
public class FileDetails extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    @NotBlank
    @Column
    private String fileName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column
    private String fileType;

    @NotBlank
    @Column
    private String filePath;    

    @Column
    private String uploadedBy;
    
    @Column
    private int uploadedDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        FileDetails ileDetails = (FileDetails) o;
        return this.fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(fileDetails.fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fileName);
    }
}
```

Whenever a file is uploaded an entry is made in the database. If a user uploads a file with the same name, a new entry is stored in the database.
But when I try to fetch it, I want the latest uploaded file details if the filename is the same. For that, I have added an override method in my model class as mentioned above. But that is returning the oldest record for each file. But I want the latest file details.

Can someone tell me what needs to be changed in the override method to achieve this?
My expectation is, I need to get the unique file names and the latest file uploaded details of those files.
Many thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Equals only determines if one file is equal to another.  Using Java how would you get all the files that would  return `true` for a particular equals comparison?  And in what data structure would they be returned (list, array?  And what format of date/time would be used to indicate modification date?

Comment: The dateformat is in epoch

Comment: First thing, I don't think overriding these equals and hash would have anything to do with what entry you will fetch from DB, you should do that in query and take only latest entry by date. Second, hash and equals method are not correct. One is case sensitive and other not, so it may happen that for two equal objects hash is different, which mustn't happen.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You would have to return them in a list or array and find the most recent.  Provide more information as requested and I can probably help.

Comment: @WJS , I'm getting a Set<FileDetails> from database.

Comment: If your getting them in a set then overriding equals will cause a problem since sets don't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Sets can't contain duplicates so this may not work if you have overridden equals.  For example, if you have many files of the same name and want the latest, then the set would only contain `one` file that returns true and it may not be the latest. So you may need to do additional processing.

For a `Set<FileDetails> set` try the following.  It will retrieve the latest `FileDetails` based on the date.  You can put this in a method of your choice.

```
FileDetails mostRecent = set.stream()
             .max(Comparator.comparing(FileDetails::getUploadedDate))
             .get();
```

The above presumes that.

- you have getters.
- the `int uploadedDate` is simply a relative value where the larger is the most recent.  And it should be unsigned so less or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
- this set only contains files that would return `true` if all compared to each other based on your comparison criteria.  May not work because duplicates are ignored in sets.

Another option would be to first filter on the name and the get the latest file for that name.

```
String filename = <some name>;
FileDetails mostRecent = set.stream().filter(FileDtails::getFileName)
             .max(Comparator.comparing(FileDetails::getUploadedDate))
             .get();
```

Note `max` returns an `Optional<FileDetails>`.  I presume that at least one file would be there so it was safe to use `get` to retrieve it from the Optional.  You can also do the following:

```
Optional<FileDetails> optional = set.stream().filter(FileDtails::getFileName)
             .max(Comparator.comparing(FileDetails::getUploadedDate));

if(optional.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(optional.get()); //gets FileDetails
} else {
    System.out.println("Details not found");
}
```

Instead of using a method reference (e.g. `FileDetails::getUploadDate`) to find the most recent you could also do it with a lambda.

```
Comparator.comparing(fd->fd.getUploadDate()) // calling the getter
// or
Comparator.comparing(fd->fd.uploadedDate) // accessing the field
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. My model class looks exactly like the one which I posted in question. Should I add getters for uploadedDate field ?

Comment: Probably since your fields are declared private.  Although within the class you can of course access private fields.